# Creating a new Draggable object with Script Tags

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to create a new Draggable object and I'm using script tags to load the plugins (no es6 build system atm). Core and interaction is loaded, everything works fine.

The problem is when I'm trying to create a new FullCalendar.Draggable(), it throws an error saying that there is no such constructor (duh).

Code example:

```
new FullCalendar.Draggable(element, {
   eventData: {
      title: "Test",
      duration: "02:00"
   }
});
```

I'm guessing that I'm either loading the plugins (scripts) wrong, or that I'm calling a non-existent constructor. It may also be that you cannot create the Draggable object with script tags?

Comment: you might well be loading things wrong, but we have no way to know, from what you've posted. There's a demo at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging-demo which has a CodePen implementation linked from it. Maybe look carefully at the CodePen and see what might be different from your version.

Comment: The difference was FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable instead of FullCalendar.Draggable